# How do I access Objective C objects without using dot notation?

Tags: objective-c

Writing the code below without dot notation, do I have this right?

from:

```
if(self.yellowViewController.view.superview == nil) {
}
```

to:

```
if([[[self yellowViewController] view] superview] == nil) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it's the same.